# Use TableModel to save and handle data or let it just show Objects (contents)

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, defaulttablemodel

I am writing an application that uses a JTable containing a model (DefaultTableModel). Now after working on it for some time I am not really sure if it's the best Idea to store all the data in the model.

What benefits are there if all the data is stored in Objects (in an ArrayList for example) and the model only shows the data from the objects of the list?

This came into my mind particularly after I need to write some sorting algorithms which would be way easier to handle on some kind of list. Also saving the "model" --> the list of objects (then) would be easier than saving a table model.

Is it more efficient to stay with my current concept (save data in model | serialize model to save table | sort model itself) or is it better to save everything in Objects each Object representing one row, which are stored in a list?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to write some sorting algorithms

JTable supports sorting of the data in the TableModel directly. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more information. So this can be handled directly by the table so you don't need external code.

> each Object representing one row, which are stored in a list?

Yes this is a valid approach, but the data must still reside in the TableModel. That is the List containing your custom Objects that represent a row in the table must be defined in the TableModel. If for some reason you need to access the List you add helper methods to the TableModel. Don't keep the data in two places.

For example, check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) which was designed for this concept. The `JButtonTableModel.java` code shows what you would need to code for each custom object you want to store in a table.